# Z axis of Plotly 3D surface not matching

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, surface, r-plotly

I am trying to understand the underlying structure of the dataframe that been used to plot the 3D surfaces in plotly

The following code is used to plot the 3D surfaces

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "surface")
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

Here the z-axis value is 189, but when I try

```
volcano[31, 20]
```

it gives me 168. So I am trying to understand from where the 189 in the picture come from?

Comment: `> volcano[21,32]
[1] 189` I think 1) `x` and `y` start at `0` in plotly, not at `1`; 2) `x` and `y` are inverted: they respectively correspond to columns and rows, not rows and columns

Comment: Minor point: `volcano` is a matrix, not a data frame

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you, that makes sense. Can I add something to this piece so that it shows in a way that it starts at 1?

Comment: johnsmith0, you can use `rbind(NA, cbind(NA, volcano))` instead of `volcano`